# Blog Functionality Within N2 CMS

Tags: blogs, n2

I've been using N2 cms for a couple of projects using some parts from their templates project but haven't come across a solid blogging component. Basically looking for something pretty simple that does tag, categories and multiple authors.

Has anyone built or used something I can plug in to N2?

If not how big a task do you think itd be to get something nice up and running?

Comment: The other thing that would be nice in such a blogging component would be if it (or indeed if N2 generally) supported the MetaWeblog API so that we could use Windows Live Writer to edit content items. I'm considering doing this myself if I can find time (or suggesting it as a feature).

Answer (score 1):

I think looking at the news example would be a good start - it has basic comment functionality.

Comment: that is basically what I ended up doing. Went with disqus for comments though.

Comment: Nice, have you thought of contributing that back into the src?